# Display a data from a MySQL database with android studio

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-layout, kotlin

I am working on a project very simple, Here is my code (XML) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my Code in Kotlin :

```
package com.test.test

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import java.util.zip.CheckedInputStream

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun GetSunset(view: View){

        val url = "mywebsite/site.php"

MyAsyncTask().execute(url)
    }

    inner class MyAsyncTask: AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        override fun onPreExecute(){

        }
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
             try{

                 val url = URL(p0[0])
                 val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                 urlConnect.connectTimeout=7000
                 var inString = ConvertStreamToString(urlConnect.inputStream)
                 publishProgress(inString)
             }catch (ex:Exception){}

            return " "
        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
            try{

// Here I don't know what I have to put ???

                //tv.text = "Hello"
                tv.text = testtext


            }catch (ex:Exception){}

        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        }

    }


    fun ConvertStreamToString(inputStream: InputStream):String{
        val bufferReader= BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        var line:String
        var AllString:String=""

        try{
            do {
                line = bufferReader.readLine()
                if (line != null) {
                    AllString += line
                }
            }while (line!=null)
                inputStream.close()
            }catch (ex:Exception){}

        return AllString


}}
```

And this is the JSON file :

```
{"response":[{"Id_number":"5","job":"Nurse"}]}
```

What I want is to extract "Nurse" that is to say I want `testtext = "Nurse"`, I precise for me all is Okay the only problem is the function `override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?)` in MainActivity

Thank you a lot for your help because I tried a lot of things but every time it does not work and I don't understand why !